# Obtain different return type objects from factory

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

I have written following code to include both N1 and N2 wcf service reference. I am attempting to write some kind of factory method to get the particular instance of the proxy object, decided at runtime.

I am not able to use proxyType out varaible assigned by factory in business code, As highlighted below. Can you please suggest what piece of info am I missing ?

How this can be achieved using generics, If my current approach is not correct? Or is there any established design pattern for this scenario ?

```
namespace N1
{
    public class Proxy1
    {
        public void foo()
        {
            //do something 
        }
    }
}

namespace N2
{
    public class Proxy2
    {
        public void foo()
        {
            //do something 
        }
    }
}

namespace N3
{
    static class Helper
    {
        public static object getProxyInstance(int i, out Type t)
        {
            object objectToReturn = null;
            t = null;
            if (i == 1)
            {
                objectToReturn = new N1.Proxy1();
                t = typeof(N1.Proxy1);
            }
            else if (i == 2)
            {
                objectToReturn = new N2.Proxy2();
                t = typeof(N2.Proxy2);
            }
            return objectToReturn;
        }
    }
}

namespace N4
{
    class BusinessClass
    {
        public void bar()
        {
            Type proxyType;
            var proxyObj = (proxyType)N3.Helper.getProxyInstance(1, out proxyType);
        }
    }
}

var proxyObj = (**proxyType**)N3.Helper.getProxyInstance(1, out proxyType);

Type or namespace proxyType could not be found.
```

EDIT : Challenge here is -
Proxy1 & Proxy2 are classes generated by add service reference command of Visual Studio. If I update service reference, my code changes will vanish, and every time I will have to re-write the code. Thus **attempting to write code without wrapping these Proxy classes, manually.**

Comment: Why won't you just have an IProxy interface which both implement.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Because Proxy1 & Proxy2 are class generated by adding service reference. If I update service reference by using Visual Studio, my code changes will vanish, and every time I will have to re-write the code.

Comment: Classes that Visual Studio generates are generally partial. Therefore you may be able to make both of your classes implement an interface by creating two new files, each also declaring the class in question as partial, and declare them both as implementers of your interface. I guess this is pretty much the reason that VS generates partial classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public interface IProxy
{
    void Foo();
}

public class Proxy1 : IProxy
{
    public void Foo()
    {
    }
}

public class Proxy2 : IProxy
{
    public void Foo()
    {
    }
}

static class Helper
{
    public static IProxy GetProxyInstance(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            return new Proxy1();
        }
        else if (i == 2)
        {
            return new Proxy1();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

class BusinessClass
{
    public void bar()
    {
        IProxy proxyObj = Helper.GetProxyInstance(1);
        proxyObj.Foo();
    }
}
```